# Multiple Google autocomplete: ValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I try to implement multiple Google maps API forms on one page. I use AngularJS and GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps' package.

I have the following HTML template:

```
<input id="{{$ctrl.element_id}}" type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.input"/>
```

and part of controller's constructor:

```
this.element_id = 'autocomplete_' + this.uuidv4()

GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById(this.element_id)),
        {types: ['establishment', 'geocode']})
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace()
      console.log(place)
      this.getAddress(place)
      safeApply()
    })
})
```

The idea is that whenever I execute google maps API component, I generate a unique `element_id` and pass it through the template and to the function `getElementById()`.

When I start my application and enter the page on which I have components with google maps autocomplete everything works great but when I enter the same page another time I get an error:

`ValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement`

Then if I refresh the page (F5), I google maps autocomplete works fine (but only once).

How can I use multiple google maps autocomplete inputs on a single page?

Comment: angularjs renders its content after js, try delaying the code by wrapping it with `$timeout()`. There is a possibility to call a digest cycle too with `$scope.$apply()` to re-render the page without F5, but timeout delay should be fine

Comment: I try to wrap it with `$timeout()` but I got an error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: timeoutProvider <- timeout. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$timeout` is a service (not global), inject it into your controller: `function($scope, $filter, ...)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried with different delays up to 5000ms. I think that it isn't related to the problem.